# Connecting to a Oracle database and displaying the contents in a web browser

Tags: node.js, oracle, dashboard, angular-fullstack, webdev.webserver

I'm new to this. Is there a way to link a Oracle database to a web browser and display it's query results in a web browser with angular or node js. Create something like a dashboard.

Basically, I'd like to know on how can we link a database (Oracle) and provide the results in a web browser. Can someone help on how this can be done using VS code?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, and many existing tools and platforms (including Oracle's own [Application Express](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/index.html) and [node-oracledb](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/nodejs.html). Your question is way too broad - we can't design a whole solution for you. (Unless you'd accept an answer of 'Yes, there is a way to do that' *8-)

Comment: See also Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS)

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches but since you are new to it, You are better of using the node-oracledb library. This link will sort you out Completely https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/

Comment: from there follow this answer to a previously asked question .and you good to go.https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045729/11734524 .I, however, feel its always good to have a bit of code you had written that failed to do what you wanted it to do attached to your question.